# Django Crm not running

Tags: django, crm

I am new in django development.I want to run django crm which source code i downloaded from code.google.com ""svn checkout http://django-crm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sample_project sample_project"".
       When i ran the sample project in it,it was giving error like "no module named Django_notify" "no module name crumbs" "no module named pagination"etc..i downloaded all these packages and there error are solved. Still "no module named crm" error is coming..please help

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = 'django_crm_test.db'             # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you are trying this .

```
pip install svn+http://django-crm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/#egg=django-crm
```

Comment: thanx for your reply..i have downloaded django crm bt still this error is coming..

Comment: now "no module name conutries" even after i have installed django-country package

Comment: Install this svn checkout http://django-countries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ django-countries           add countries to the list of installed apps  in settings.py

Comment: thnx for ur help..now i am getting this error  ""database is improperly configured please supply engine value" The default value is sqlite3..still im getting this error..

Comment: could you please post your setings.py file then only  i can help you now

Comment: DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'  i have used

Comment: this is not the proper way post your settings.py file i wil correct that

Comment: sorry can i have your email id? i will send it to you..iam unable to post it

Answer (score 0):

try new django crm in github. It's opensource CRM developed with django.

https://github.com/MicroPyramid/Django-CRM